# Specifying a custom certificate chain leads to "unable to get local issuer certificate"-error

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Bear with me please, for I am losing my mind over this. I have changed the name of my domain to `example.com` in this post for privacy.

## The problem

I have a server running nginx with a Letsencrypt TLS certificate. It looks like this according to `openssl s_client`:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = example.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
```

I want make a request to this server in a python script. This script works:

```py
import requests
requests.get('https://example.com/')
```

To make my script independent from my systems SSL configuration, I have copied the server's certificate `fullchain.pem` over to my client and specified it in my script:

```py
import requests
requests.get('https://example.com/', verify='/home/jan/fullchain.pem')
```

This gives me:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
```

## What I have tried

- Maybe the requests module only wants to know the certificate chain without the concrete `example.com` certificate. So I have deleted the first certificate block from `/home/jan/fullchain.pem`. Still the same error.
- I have noticed `fullchain.pem` doesn't actually include the root certificate. So I have downloaded the root certificate from [sslchecker.com](https://www.sslchecker.com/) and appended it to `/home/jan/fullchain.pem`. Still the same error.
- I have noticed that running `openssl verify` on my server's certificate returns `error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate`. Maybe I should also append the root certificate to my server's certificate file. This makes nginx throw an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_set0_chain("/root/.ssl/actualfull.pem") failed (SSL: error:1415418E:SSL routines:ssl_cert_set0_chain:ca md too weak)
```

## My question

1. Why does `openssl verify` fail on the unmodified SSL certificate chain provided by letsencrypt?
2. Why does nginx give an error when I append the root certificate to the chain?
3. And most importantly: **How can I specify the certificate chain in my python script without getting an error?**

Comment: pretty much the issue here... any luck?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong nope :(
I guess It's comforting I'm not the only one having the problem. Not to beg but maybe someone else will find the question if you upvote